# Verificar se uma string é composta por digitos

Tags: c

Quero verificar se as minhas strings (que estão guardadas numa matriz), são inteiros ou não por exemplo a para a quarta linha da matriz tenho o seguinte código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct informacaoFicheiroInput{
int id;
int acompanhantes;
char tipo[13];
int entrada;
int saida;
int servico;

};

void toString(struct informacaoFicheiroInput info){

   if(strcmp("Visitante",info.tipo) == 0){

   printf("ID: %d | ",info.id);
   printf("%s | ",info.tipo);
   printf("Entrada: %d | ", info.entrada);
   printf("Saida: %d | ",info.saida);
   printf("Serviço: %d\n",info.servico);

   }else{
   printf("ID: %d | ",info.id);
   printf("Acompanhantes: %d | ",info.acompanhantes);
   printf("Tipo: %s | ",info.tipo);
   printf("Entrada: %d | ", info.entrada);
   printf("Saida: %d | \n",info.saida);
   }
}

int validacaoVisitante(char dados[5][20]){

if(atoi(dados[0]) == 0  ){ //validação do ID
    return 0;
}

    //Validação da entrada
if(!isDigit(dados[2]) || atoi(dados[2])>24 || atoi(dados[2])<0){
     return 0;
}
    //Validação saida
if (!isDigit(dados[3]) || atoi(dados[3])>24 || atoi(dados[3])<=0){
     return 0;
}


    //validação do serviço
if(!isDigit(dados[4]) && dados[4] == 0){
     return 0;
}
return 1;

}


int isDigit(char *string){
char *p;
int firstDigit = 0; // A princípio, nenhum dígito foi encontrado.
int lastDigit = 0;  // A princípio, nenhum dígito foi encontrado.
int result = 1;     // A princípio, considera-se verdadeiro, que é digito.

p = string;

while (*p){
    if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9'){
        p++;
        firstDigit = 1;
    }
    else if (*p == ' ' && !firstDigit){
        p++;
    }
    else if (*p == ' ' && firstDigit && !lastDigit){
        lastDigit = 1;
        p++;
    }
    else if (*p == ' ' && lastDigit){
        p++;
    }
    else{
        result = 0;
        break;
    }
}

return firstDigit && result;
}


void lerFicheiroInput(){
struct informacaoFicheiroInput informacao[20];
int tokenCount=0;
FILE* file;
file = fopen("input.txt","r");

if(file == NULL){
    printf("Não foi possivel abrir o arquivo.\n");
}

char line[100], *token, dados[5][20];
int info = 0;

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL){
    int count=0,i=0;
    token = strtok(line," ; ");

    while(token != NULL && count < 15){

        strcpy(dados[count++], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ; ");
        i++;
        tokenCount++;
    }

    // Mete os dados lidos da info-esima linha
    // em informacao.
    if(strcmp("Visitante", dados[1]) == 0 && validacaoVisitante(dados)==1){
       informacao[info].id = atoi(dados[0]);
       strcpy(informacao[info].tipo, dados[1]);
       informacao[info].entrada = atoi(dados[2]);
       informacao[info].saida = atoi(dados[3]);
       informacao[info].servico = atoi(dados[4]);
       info++;
    }else if (atoi(dados[0])!=0 &&(strcmp("Diretor",dados[2])==0 || 
strcmp("Funcionario",dados[2])==0)) {
       informacao[info].id = atoi(dados[0]);
       informacao[info].acompanhantes = atoi(dados[1]);
       strcpy(informacao[info].tipo, dados[2]);
       informacao[info].entrada = atoi(dados[3]);
       informacao[info].saida = atoi(dados[4]);
       info++;
   }
    count++;
}

fclose(file);
for(int j = 0; j< info; j++){
   toString(informacao[j]);
}


}


void main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
lerFicheiroInput();

}
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de entrada ?

Comment: Eu tenho um ficheiro com linhas do genero
2 ; 12 ; Funcionario ; 10 ; 5
E estou a divida-las desta maneira (" ; "), contando os espaços antes e depois do ";" depois queria fazer essa verificação para saber se por exemplo num parâmetro que deveria ter um inteiro tenho uma string ou um float, por exemplo

Comment: faltou informar a linguagem que está utilizando.

Comment: está na tag, em baixo

Comment: Tira todos os `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)` e deixa só o "recheio" dos `for` porque não estás a iterar sobre `dados`, ou seja, não estás a usar o índice `i` para nada. No mais, põe `atoi(dados[4]) == 0`, no último `if` da função, no lugar de `dados[4] == 0`

Comment: Ah sim faz sentido! E sim tbm já reparei no == 
Como faço para percorrer todas as linhas e comparar o Id de cada uma?

Comment: Tens que usar uma estrutura que tenha todas as informações de todas as linhas. Tens algo assim?

Comment: Sim tenho tudo, posso atualizar o código em cima, mas ainda são algumas linhas de código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int isDigit(char *string)
{
    char *p;
    int firstDigit = 0; // A princípio, nenhum dígito foi encontrado.
    int lastDigit = 0;  // A princípio, nenhum dígito foi encontrado.
    int result = 1;     // A princípio, considera-se verdadeiro, que é digito.

    p = string;

    while (*p)
    {
        if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9')
        {
            ++p;
            firstDigit = 1;
        }
        else if (*p == ' ' && !firstDigit)
        {
            ++p;
        }
        else if (*p == ' ' && firstDigit && !lastDigit)
        {
            lastDigit = 1;
            ++p;
        }
        else if (*p == ' ' && lastDigit)
        {
            ++p;
        }
        else
        {
            result = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return firstDigit && result;
}
```

Uso:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
    if (!isDigit(dados[3][i]))
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
```

Comment: Marcelo como passaria o ponteiro da string dados[3] por exemplo?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Se encontrar algum erro peço um esclarecimento, mas tem sido uma grande ajuda neste projeto!

Comment: Marcelo para as linhas de visitantes fiz a seguinte função: validaçãoVisitante, editei no código em cima, agora já não me está a guardar nenhum visitante, o que estou a fazer mal?

Comment: Para saber se é um registro de visitante, não basta comparar `dados[1]` com `" Visitante "`?

Comment: Sim essa parte já está, mas temos várias validações para fazer, são considerados dados inválidos os seguintes:
 Linhas com informação insuficiente.
 Linhas com informação em excesso.
 Linhas com dados de tipos inválidos.
 Linhas com pessoas cuja representação seja inválida.
 Não se sabe quantas entradas existem no ficheiro.
 Não pode existir mais de uma entrada por pessoa.
 O visitante não pode visitar um serviço cujo funcionário ainda não entrou.
As pessoas, sejam elas visitantes ou funcionários, com o número 5 e/ou 10 não podem entrar

Comment: Falta apenas fazer a validação se o ID é igual ou nao

Comment: Comentei na tua pergunta, vê lá.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `isdigit()` da biblioteca padrão `ctype.h`. Veja só:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int isDigit( const char * str )
{
    if(!str) return 0;     /* Se string for NULL, retorna 0 */
    if(!(*str)) return 0;  /* Se string for VAZIA, retorna 0 */

    while( *str )
        if( !isdigit( *str++ ) )
            return 0;     

    return 1;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "1234567890" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( " 123" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "987 " ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "1234aeiou" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "  ABC1234567 " ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( NULL ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Caso você queira ignorar os `espaços em branco` contidos antes e/ou depois dos digitos, você pode combinar as funções `isdigit()` e `isblank()`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int isDigit( const char * str )
{
    int ret = 0;

    if(!str) return 0;
    if(!(*str)) return 0;

    while( isblank( *str ) )
        str++;

    while( *str )
    {
        if( isblank( *str ) )
            return ret;

        if( !isdigit( *str ) )
            return 0;

        ret = 1;

        str++;
    }

    return ret;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "1234567890" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( " 123" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "987 " ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( " 567 " ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( " 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 " ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "1234aeiou" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "  ABC1234567 " ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( "" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isDigit( NULL ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: como uso o atoi para passar de string para inteiros, a função original isDigit diz que NULL é = a 0. o que para o meu programa infelizmente não me é util

Comment: A função `atoi()` não detecta erros e retorna `0` sempre que falha! Se você passar um valor `NULL` para `atoi()`, ele se comporta de maneira **indefinida**, provavelmente acasionando em uma desastrosa falha de segmentação!

Comment: Se o seu intento é fazer com que a função `isDigit()` proposto na minha resposta retorne algo diferente de `0` caso a entrada seja `NULL`, basta alterar a linha `if(!str) return 0;`. Veja os comentários no código.

Comment: `isDigit("0 1 2 3 4 5");` retornaria 1

Comment: @MarceloUchimura: ops! Resolvido!

Comment: `isDigit("987 ");` não retorna 1.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura: ufff, agora sim está resolvido!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int verifica(char *nome);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char nomes[4][100];
  int tam, resultado;
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    scanf("%s", nomes[i]);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     tam = strlen(nomes[i]);
     resultado = verifica(nomes[i]);
     if(resultado == tam) //se o tamanho for igual o ao que função retornar ele só contem numeros
     {
        printf("%s\n", nomes[i]);
     }
  }
   return 0;
}

int verifica(char *nome)
{
  int tam = strlen(nome), cont = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
  {
     if(nome[i] >= '0' && nome[i] <= '9') // se ele for numero, o contador e incrementado
     {
        cont++;
     }
  }
  return cont;
}
```